# WiFi & GbE Slow while Both Active

Tags: windows-xp, networking, wireless-networking, gigabit-ethernet

I'm having a problem with my WiFi network connection when I use my wired GbE connection concurrently on my Laptop. I'm using my WiFi for Internet access, and general web surfing and I'm using my GbE connection to connect to my PlayStation so I can stream media. The WiFi connection is via a Linksys 610N connected to my Cable Modem. Where as the GbE connection is a direct connection from my Ethernet port to the Ethernet port of the PS3 via a Cat-5 cable (no router in between this connection).

As soon as I connect the cable from the PS3 to my Ethernet port on my Laptop the WiFi connection slows to a halt, but then allows for a connection to the web as normal but at much slower speeds for the things like BitTorrent that stops completely.

It seems to me that Windows can't handle both connections at once. It will have both active but it can only accept and send packets on one device at one time. I can get WiFi connections to work to go to websites and the like, but once I use my GbE connection to share media between my Laptop and my PS3 the Wifi connection dies out and I no longer have access to the internet.

I setup my connection on the PS3 and the Laptop following the insturctions posted here:
http://forums.finalgear.com/problems/s14e01-ps3-size-problem-40642/#post1188132

And the following is the results of my ipconfig.

```
Windows IP Configuration
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : dygear
    Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter WiFi:
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel(R) PRO/Wireless 3945ABG Network Connection
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-19-**-**-**-**
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
    Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.111
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
                                        167.206.254.2
                                        167.206.254.1
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, May 19, 2010 08:55:30
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Thursday, May 20, 2010 08:55:30

Ethernet adapter LAN:
    Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
    Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
    Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-16-**-**-**-**
    Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.50
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bad idea to use the same IP subnet for two separate networks. In many respects, you're lucky it works at all. Since you're using 192.168.1/24 for your wireless interface, you should use something else for your wired Ethernet interface. You could simply make it 192.168.2/24. Don't forget to change it on both your PS3 *and* your laptop's Ethernet interface.

Give that a try and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: That's very cool. Did not know that I need to do that thank you.